# Use identify tool on a specific coordinate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, find, identify

Just a simple question. I would like to use the identify tool for a specific coordinate to get the pixel value. Unfortunately it's not possible to place the cursor that precisely. I used the go to xy tool to set a point but even that doesn't help.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a workflow that I sometimes use for this, but it's not that straight-forward.

Create a point FC and, with the use of `F6` manually enter coordinates for the points where you want to extract values from your raster.

Run [Extract values to Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002t000000) on your points and raster (requires Spatial Analyst).

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
>   and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
>   class.